# Git diff between two commits in the same remote branch

Tags: git, git-diff

How to get git diff between two commits in a remote branch?

For example I have remote branch remotes/origin/some-remote-branch. The remote branch has commit which I am interested on. So I want to get diff for that commit and store it in a local file.

I have cloned repository locally. But locally I checked out another branch 'some-another-branch' so I have many uncommitted files locally in 'some-another-branch'. So, I do not want to check out to remotes/origin/some-remote-branch because I am working with other branch. I just want to get diff from remotes/origin/some-remote-branch for particular commit and store it to a file.

Comment: Consider using `git patch` if you want to keep changes but don't want to commit them.

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff commit1 commit2 >diff.patch
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203

Comment: Note that `commit1` or `commit2` can be `origin/some-remote-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

To see what changes in `commit2` compared to `commit1`, run this command:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

The output is a patch in which when we apply it to `commit1`, we have `commit2`. Thus, the order of the two commits in the command above is important.

In your example, you need to run:

```
git diff HEAD particularcommit
```

Just in case you don’t know HEAD: it is your current commit - the commit that you have checked out.

To save the output patch to a file, just append `> file.patch` to the command.